# Gradle plugin task to verify dependencies

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create a task in a Gradle plugin which verifies certain aspects of the dependencies on the project.

Here's what I have right now

```
class StandardsPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        // register configuration block
        project.extensions.create('standards', StandardsExtension)

        // ... snip ...

        project.tasks.create('snapshotPolicy', SnapshotPolicyTask)
                //.mustRunAfter(':compileClasspath')
                //.mustRunAfter(project.tasks.findByName('compileJava'))

        //project.tasks.findByName("check").dependsOn("snapshotPolicy")

    }
}

class SnapshotPolicyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def snapshotPolicy() {
        println 'SnapshotPolicyTask#snapshotPolicy'
        String version = project.version.toString()

        // no enforcement for snapshot builds
        if (version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT"))
            return

        println 'testing dependencies'

        project.getConfigurations().all { configuration ->
            println 'configuration ' + configuration

            configuration.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { dependency ->
                println 'dependency ' + dependency.requested

                if (dependency.requested.version?.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT"))
                    throw new GradleException("Found SNAPSHOT dependency: " + dependency.requested)
            }
        }
    }
}

// in the test

    def "snapshot dependency is denied for non-snapshot build"() {
        given:
        buildFile.newWriter().withWriter {
            it << """
            plugins {
                id 'java-library'
                id 'standards'
            }

            version = '1.2.3'
            
            dependencies {
              implementation 'org.example:example:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
            }
            """
        }
        when:
        def result = GradleRunner.create()
                .withProjectDir(testProjectDir.root)
                .withArguments('snapshotPolicy')
                .withPluginClasspath()
                .build()

        println result.output
        then:
        result.output.contains("SnapshotPolicyTask#snapshotPolicy")
        //result.task(":snapshotPolicy").outcome == FAILED
    }
```

when I run the test, it runs the task, but there are no dependencies found

```
> Task :snapshotPolicy
SnapshotPolicyTask#snapshotPolicy
testing dependencies
configuration configuration ':annotationProcessor'
configuration configuration ':api'
configuration configuration ':apiElements'
configuration configuration ':archives'
configuration configuration ':compile'
configuration configuration ':compileClasspath'
configuration configuration ':compileOnly'
configuration configuration ':compileOnlyApi'
configuration configuration ':default'
configuration configuration ':implementation'
configuration configuration ':runtime'
configuration configuration ':runtimeClasspath'
configuration configuration ':runtimeElements'
configuration configuration ':runtimeOnly'
configuration configuration ':testAnnotationProcessor'
configuration configuration ':testCompile'
configuration configuration ':testCompileClasspath'
configuration configuration ':testCompileOnly'
configuration configuration ':testImplementation'
configuration configuration ':testRuntime'
configuration configuration ':testRuntimeClasspath'
configuration configuration ':testRuntimeOnly'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

You can see the various things I've tried to get the task to execute after whatever it is that configures the dependencies, but with no luck.

What am I missing?